# What's the word for a boolean and statement stopping if the first returns false?

Tags: boolean, terminology, boolean-expression

Sorry the title isn't descriptive, but if I could describe it well I probably would've found my answer.

In Python, if you were to run the following:

```
def fun1():
    print("fun1 runs")
    return False

def fun2():
    print("fun2 runs")
    return True

x = fun1() and fun2()
```

It would print the statement

```
fun1 runs
```

because after `fun1` returns False, `x` will be false regardless of what `fun2` is so `fun2` never runs.

What's the word for this? I ask because I wanted to search if PHP boolean expressions do the same thing but didn't know what it was called.

Sorry for asking a silly question about terminology, but it's been bugging me!

Comment: [Short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I got you right then you are talking about short-circuit evaluation